# How to create separate log files?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I'm using [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.43/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm) to create log files, but it is appending to a single log file;
instead, I want to create a separate log file for each execution of my script.

**How can I create separate log files ?**

Here is my code :

**fetch.pl**

```
#Opening Log configuration file
Log::Log4perl::init('./logs/log4perl.conf');
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('./logs_$$.logs');
```

**logs.conf**

```
log4perl.logger = TRACE,  FileAppndr1
log4perl.logger.logs = DEBUG, FileAppndr1
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1 = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1.filename = logs.log 
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logfile name is set in the config file, not in the call to `get_logger()`. So you need to find out how to use variables in the config file. The [Log4Perl FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html) contains the question "[What if I need dynamic values in a static Log4perl configuration file?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aFAQ#What-if-I-need-dynamic-values-in-a-static-Log4perl-configuration-file)"

The important part of the answer is:

> As of Log::Log4perl 0.28, every value in the configuration file can be
>   specified as a Perl hook. So, instead of saying
>
> ```
> log4perl.appender.Logfile.filename = test.log
> ```
>
> you could just as well have a Perl subroutine deliver the value
>   dynamically:
>
> ```
> log4perl.appender.Logfile.filename = sub { logfile(); };
> ```
>
> given that logfile() is a valid function in your main package
>   returning a string containing the path to the log file.

So it looks like you want:

```
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1.filename = sub { "logs_$$.log" };
```

Answer (score 2):

To get variable interpolation in strings you'll have to use double quotes:

```
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("./logs_$$.logs");
```

Or concatenation:

```
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('./logs_' . $$ . '.logs');
```

Comment: I have changed it to double quotes in fetch.pl But Same thing again.  Actually it is creating log file with logs.log which I have mentioned in logs.conf file.

Comment: I don't think you're using the `get_logger()` sub right, I can't find any example in the documentation of using it with a file name. As for the file name, you might have to set it up programmatically. The `filename` part in the log is not right, right?

Comment: Same logs.conf file I'm using to create logs. But it is creating with log.logs. I'm unable to set programmatically. How to set it? Do I need to change anything in logs.conf?

Comment: @user123 I don't *know*, but my best *guess* is that the hardcoded filename in the conf would have to go.